# mailto crontab doesn't work

Tags: email, cron, mailto

I'm running a script on my mybookworld(NAS) via crontab every day. And it would be nice if it could send me everyday an email report with the output of the script.

So I looked at MAILTO in crontabs, but it doesn't send me anything at all. The script ran correctly at the right time, but there was no email.
This is my crontab:

```
~ # crontab -l
MAILTO=x.y@googlemail.com

0 0 * * * python /root/erepCrawler/src/main.py
```

I've written a "smaller" crontab for testing reasons:

```
MAILTO=x.y@googlemail.com
* * * * * echo "blaah"
```

This should send me every minute an email with "blaah" as the body. If I'm wrong please correct me.

Is there another package needed for sending mails with crontab? sendmail is installed in /opt/sbin/sendmail.

Comment: I guess you didn't set up any mail transport agent appropriately, did you?  Can you send mails from command line, e.g. `echo Test | mail -s Test x.y@googlemail.com`

Comment: i think you are right. There is not even installed something named mail. After a bit of googling i'm trying now to install postfix on the Nas. With this, i should work right?

Comment: If postfix is configured correctly (expecially relay server etc.) it should work.

Answer (score 14):

It should work in the cron with following modifications:

```
MAILTO="x.y@googlemail.com"
* * * * * echo blaah
```

works on my server, just tested.

Comment: Well, i think the " isn't the point (see bml's comment). But it is good to know, that the `echo "blaah"` works if the mail thing is installed correctly:) thanks for the help

Comment: are the quotes needed? I am trying to debug my problem.

Comment: Quotes not needed, the following is perfectly valid
MAILTO=email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com

Comment: Quotes needed for no email! Took quite a while to figure out.

Comment: I did tried without quotes and It works as all email users received the email. In my case, it wasn't working because I was emailing the output and trying to write it to a file at the same time which means the following code, it won't work. 
`MAILTO=me@example.com,coleague@example.com`    
`* * * * * echo 'blah' >> /tmp/logs/blah.log`

Comment: You need to have a working MTA (mail transport agent) installed and configured for the MAILTO to work properly

Answer (score 2):

after spending hours debugging why this wasn't working with nullmailer on my Debian box, I discovered I had a filter at gmail sending everything from cron to "All Mail" without going through my inbox... just something to check.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add this to `/etc/hosts` so that mail to anyone at my server's own FQDN  would be resolved:

`127.0.0.1   mydomain.com.`

Notice the dot at the end.  In my case, I'm sending email essentially to root@localhost with `MAILTO=root` which gets translated to root@mydomain.com.

[Here's some more detail on this answer.](https://serverfault.com/questions/115790/mailto-is-not-working-for-cron-how-can-i-fix-this/869007#869007)